# scala: tracing implicits selection and other code magics

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

When trying to figure how a library works, implicit conversions are confusing. For example,  looking at an expression like 'val foo: Foo = 1', what converts 1 to Foo?

Is it possible to instruct the scala library (or REPL) to print out the code paths that are executing while evaluating an expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add "-Xprint:typer" to the compiler command line (or "-Ybrowse:typer" for a swing GUI browser) to see the code with the conversions explicitly applied.

Comment: What do you mean by swing GUI browser?

Comment: Swing = java client side GUI widgets.  GUI = Graphical User Interface.  "Swing GUI Browser" = ugly dialog box with expandable tree control in it.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to printing out the conversions, one must realize implicits can't just come out of the blue. You have to bring them into scope in some way. The alternatives are:

1. Explicit `import` statement. Watch out for `import x.y._` when `y` is an object, as this is the only way to bring in an implicit into scope.
2. The object companion of the class that is being converted into something else.
3. The object companion of the target class, as long as that target is made explicit somehow (such as in your example).

Note that the object `scala.Predef` is all imported into scope by default, which is how Scala's default implicits get into scope.

Comment: about (1). actually, this question stems from the fact that to use scalacheck you 'import org.scalacheck._' and then you can do things like "val vowel: Gen[Char] = 'A' | 'E' | 'I' | 'O' | 'U' | 'Y'", which obviously uses implicit conversions. It turns out that one of the scalacheck files has 'import Gen.{value,...}' (value is the implicit method that does the conversion)

Comment: I doubt that import is the relevant one. I'd look inside Gen's object companion for an implicit in this case.

Comment: Yes, from the companion object, but I didn't need to do 'import org.scalacheck.Gen._' to get it, so importing the implicit was implicitly done (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

`scalac -print` prints the code after implicit type conversions where applied.

```
class A{
    val x : String = "hi" drop 1 
}
```

Will result in:

```
package <empty> {
  class A extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    @remote def $tag(): Int = scala.ScalaObject$class.$tag(A.this);
    private[this] val x: java.lang.String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def x(): java.lang.String = A.this.x;
    def this(): A = {
      A.super.this();
      A.this.x = scala.this.Predef.forceRandomAccessCharSeq(
        scala.this.Predef.stringWrapper("hi").drop(1));
      ()
    }
  }
}
```