# Where is the implicit conversion from Query to UnitInvoker comming from?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalaquery

In these examples ( https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/wiki/Queries) foreach (via for comprehension) is used on a scalaquery Query.

But foreach doesn't seem to be present in `Query`, but only in `UnitInvoker`.

Where is the implicit conversion comming from that converts from `Query` to `UnitInvoker`?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818181/scala-tracing-implicits-selection-and-other-code-magics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: from the [`BasicImplicitConversions`](https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalaquery/ql/basic/BasicImplicitConversions.scala) trait.

Usually with ScalaQuery you'll bring these conversions into scope by importing the contents of the `Implicit` field of the profile for your driver:

```
import org.scalaquery.ql.extended.H2Driver.Implicit._
```